How to add data-autoload, data-origin and data-callback script tags in Angular typescript
I want to add my script in angular application which contains 'data-autoload, data-origin  and data-callback' keys. I tried with _renderer2.createElement('script') method but it is throwing error.
Code
 let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
 script.type="application/javascript";
 script.data-autoload" =""
 script.data-origin" =""
 script.data-callback" =""

this._renderer2.appendChild(this.document.body,script)

Error
error ';' expected  at

and same error for data-origin and data-callback
Kindly help me to resolve this issue

You have an invalid javascript variable.
Rules for variable name:

Spaces are not allowed in variable names.
Hyphens are not allowed in variable names.
Only letters, numbers, underscores, and dollar signs are permitted in variable names.
Case matters when it comes to variable names.
Variable name always starts with a letter (alphabet), underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($), i.e. any other special characters not allowed.
Reserved keywords are not allowed.

Reference link
The code fix for this is to use setAttribute instead.
  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'application/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('data-autoload', '');
    script.setAttribute('data-origin', '');
    script.setAttribute('data-callback', '');
    this._renderer2.appendChild(document.body,script)
  }

Stackblitz Demo
